# How to cross compile for ARM on Ubuntu conditionally?

Tags: c, makefile, cross-compiling, gnu-make

I have written the following make file

```
all: writer.o

writer.o:
    gcc -Wall writer.c -o writer

clean:
    rm *.o
```

How do I add a functionality to this make file such that I am able to generate an application for the native build platform when GNU make variable CROSS_COMPILE is not specified on the make command line.However, when CROSS_COMPILe is set, I should generate a cross compiled output file using the compiler, aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc.

Comment: This makefile is *wrong*. You've got a object as a target / rule, and you're compiling a binary instead of the object. It works in this case, but it's just wrong generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `CROSS_COMPILE` variable itself to the compiler prefix. So for native builds:

```
CROSS_COMPILE =
```

(i.e. there's nothing, the variable is "empty").

And for cross-compilation:

```
CROSS_COMPILE = aarch64-none-linux-gnu-
```

Then set:

```
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
```

---

To complement the above, use *implicit rules* to build the program:

```
all: writer

writer: writer.o
```

That's all that you need.